# Prove that an Euclidean-open ball is open under the supremum metric

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Consider the metric space $(\mathbb{R}^2,d_\infty)$ where $d_\infty(x,y)=\max_{i\in\{1,2\}}\left\{|x_i-y_i|\right\}$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^2$. And consider the set $A=
\left\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2:\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}<1\right\}$. I've got to show that the set $A$ is open in the $(\mathbb{R}^2,d_\infty)$ metric space.

If we let $d_2(u,w)=\sqrt{(u_1-w_1)^2+(u_2-w_2)^2}$, $u,w\in\mathbb{R^2}$, then $A$ is just a $d_2$-open ball with radius $1$ and centered at $(0,0)=\boldsymbol{0}$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$, i.e., $A=B_{d_1}(\boldsymbol{0},1)$.

I make use of the proposition that the $d_\infty$ and $d_2$ metrics are equivalent under the following inequality in $\mathbb{R^n}$: $d_\infty(x,y)\le d_2(x,y)\le \sqrt{n}d_\infty(x,y)$ with $x,y\in\mathbb{R^n}$.

*Proof.*  Let $x\in A$, so since $A$ is an open set we can choose an $r_0>0$ such that $B_{d_2}(x,r_0)\subset A$. Now let $r=r_0/\sqrt{2}$ and $z\in B_{d_\infty}(x,r)$, thus $d_\infty(x,z)<r$. By the equivalence between $d_2$ and $d_\infty$, we have that:

$$d_2(x,z)\le\sqrt{2}d_\infty(x,z)$$
$$(1/\sqrt{2})d_2(x,z)\le d_\infty(x,z)<r=r_0/\sqrt{2}$$
$$(1/\sqrt{2})d_2(x,z)<r_0/\sqrt{2}$$
$$d_2(x,z)<r_0$$

Meaning that $z\in B_{d_2}(x,r_0)$, thus $B_{d_\infty}(x,r)\subset B_{d_2}(x,r_0)$ implying $B_{d_\infty}(x,r)\subset A$, that is, $A$ is open in the $(\mathbb{R}^2,d_\infty)$ metric space.

Is this proof right? Would you have any recommendations?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think the proof should be very easy actually and yours seems rather technical. You know the inequalities

$$d_\infty ≤ d_2 ≤ \sqrt{n}d_\infty, $$
these show that both maps $id:(\mathbb{R}^n,d_2)\to (\mathbb{R}^n,d_\infty)$ and $id:(\mathbb{R}^n,d_\infty)\to (\mathbb{R}^n,d_2)$ are continuous. Since they are inverse to each other they are both open. In particular the first map is open. So it maps open balls to open sets, done.